What's going on with internal forces and reaction forces?

I thought the reaction force should go downward at B but textbook says upward. If it goes up, doesn't that mean its a tensile force? I don't think there's any tension in the system. Also, when you cut the bar into pieces, for part c (that's the lower part), shouldn't it be internal force and load P as well, cause it's going downward?

This question is similar to: Why is the reaction force at A upward? Shouldn't it be downard?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A metal bar will deflect under its weight by
$$\Delta L= \frac{\int_{0}^{L}A\rho. d L}{AE}$$

A area of bar

L length off bar

E modulus of elasticity

$\rho$ specific density


Therefore if the distance between the top and bottom supports is not  $L- \Delta L \ $ say its distance is $L$The top support will have an upward reaction.

Not exactly sure what the question is here, but I'll take a shot at clarifying.
We have a pin at points A and B. The pin allows for rotation, but will resist translation. So, if the force P "tries" to move the block downward, then the pins at A and B will resist this force by opposing it. In order to oppose the downward force, $R_A$ and $R_B$ must point upwards.
In this case, $R_A$ is a tensile force, while $R_B$ is a compressive force. $R_A$ will try to "stretch" the top  portion of the block, because force $P$ is trying to move the block away from pin A. $R_B$ will "squish" the bottom portion of the block, because force $P$ is trying to move the block towards pin B. However, because the block is pinned at both ends, it won't actually have a displacement; that is, its length will be the same as if there were no force:
$$\delta_A - \delta_B = 0 \implies \delta_A = \delta_B$$
About your last point--I think the diagram shows something different from what you might be thinking. The bottom half of the images displays portions of the block not including the portion affected by force $P$. So, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are necessarily internal forces. Their magnitude is changed by the presence of force $P$, but that doesn't mean you have to label it $P_1 + P$, as I think you might be implying.

Textbooks have implicit assumptions that we must accept, and we refer to them as conventions. Therefore, what I deduce from the image you provided, is that we must accept first how unknown upward vertical reactions are assumed to be positive - that is, " $\uparrow$ is $+$ ". This aims to reduce confusion in solving and shall be proven by subsequent equations using $R_A$ and $R_B$, instead of the more confusing $-R_A$ and $-R_B$...
...unless, of course, the textbook assumes upward to be negative, or " $\downarrow$ is $+$ ", from where I shall digress. Hence, for your question, I shall proceed with the " $\uparrow$ is $+$ " convention.
Knowing this, we can proceed with the equations, and in the solution, only one of two cases shall be correct:
a) if the value of $R_A$ is $+$, then the direction assumption is correct - the actual reaction does move upward ($\uparrow$)... or,
b) if the value of $R_A$ is $-$, then the direction assumption is wrong - the actual reaction instead moves downward ($\downarrow$)...
...and the same goes for $R_B$.
What about tension and compression? Well, these aspects are only considered as internal forces, and for this we usually (1) start from a reference node, which is any of the pinned supports in this case, then we (2) move along the member to determine forces that cause changes in what the member internally feels, which is $P$ in this case. This process regards actual values as causing value changes and sign changes.
From what I see, the textbook only illustrates how at such a cut, the internal forces $P_1$ and $P_2$ will be opposite in direction when you move along the member (partly due to convention for internal forces), but not equal in value due to the differing lengths (hence, not shown as both $P_1$).
Note how $P$ is an applied force, while $P_1$ and $P_2$ are internal forces.
